# Fruit ripening dataset

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a dataset containing how fast each fruit ripens, given different conditions such as:

- temperature
- humidity
- other fruits located nearby

Comment: The 'other fruits nearby' is quite unscientific.  More scientific would be the concentration of ethylene gas, and then consult [lists of ethylene sensitive & ethylene producing fruits](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/4993/67).